# C++ std::array as a parameter of overloaded function is ambiguous

Tags: c++, overloading, ambiguous, stdarray

I was expecting the compiler to choose which function to use, depending on the size of the array. It works properly on call `funct({1,2,3});`, but the others are ambiguous, why? Isn't `array<int,1>` a different data type from `array<int,2>`, `array<int,3>`, and so on?

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
using namespace std;
void funct(array<int,1>one)
{
    cout<<"one"<<endl;
}
void funct(array<int,2>two)
{
    cout<<"two"<<endl;
}
void funct(array<int,3>three)
{
    cout<<"three"<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    funct({1,2,3});
    funct({1,2});
    funct({1});
    return(0);
}
```

Here are my build messages (`[redacted]` is what i removed for obvious reasons):

```
||=== Build: Debug in ambiguitytest (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
[redacted]\ambiguitytest\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
[redacted]\ambiguitytest\main.cpp|19|error: call of overloaded 'funct(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous|
[redacted]\ambiguitytest\main.cpp|8|note: candidate: void funct(std::array<int, 2u>)|
[redacted]\ambiguitytest\main.cpp|12|note: candidate: void funct(std::array<int, 3u>)|
[redacted]\ambiguitytest\main.cpp|20|error: call of overloaded 'funct(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous|
[redacted]\ambiguitytest\main.cpp|4|note: candidate: void funct(std::array<int, 1u>)|
[redacted]\ambiguitytest\main.cpp|8|note: candidate: void funct(std::array<int, 2u>)|
[redacted]\ambiguitytest\main.cpp|12|note: candidate: void funct(std::array<int, 3u>)|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: `{1}` is not an array but an initializer list.  That list will initialize any size array.

Comment: `funct(std::array{1,2});` (using C++17 CTAD) would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `std::array<int, N>` can be initialized with a braced initializer list of any length up to `N`. It performs aggregate initialization and initializes the remaining elements of the array to zero.

So for both `funct({1,2});` and `funct({1});` multiple overload candidates are viable.

There is no rule that makes an aggregate initialization with more matching elements a better match in overload resolution, so overload resolution is ambiguous.

If you need to determine the length of the initializer list, you can use a template instead:

```
template<std::size_t N>
void funct(const int (&arr)[N])
{
    if(N == 1)
        cout<<"one"<<endl;
    else if(N == 2)
        cout<<"two"<<endl;
    else if(N == 3)
        cout<<"one"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"something else"<<endl;
}
```

(Note that this only works with references to built-in arrays as function parameter. It doesn't work with `std::array`. Built-in arrays have special deduction rules that allow this.)